# Закрасить ячейку в зависимости от значения

Tags: python, excel, google-spreadsheet

В ячейку приходят два числа: первое - 1 или 2, второе - от 1 до 90.
В зависимости от первого числа нужно закрасить ячейку в один из двух цветов, и взначении оставить только второе число.

Например:

1,45 - красная ячейка, остается значение 45

2,32 - зеленая ячейка, остается значение 32

Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: если поможет, то в libre это делается с помощью `Формат→Условное форматирование`.

Comment: и какая будет формула?

Comment: Числа приходят одно за другим (через время) или  это одно значение (два числа, разделенны запятой)? В любом случае условное форматирование не поможет, нужен макрос: в первом варианте нужно залить ячейку цветом первого числа, при входе второго числа заливка не должна поменяться; во втором варианте по первому числу залить ячейку и оставить только второе... Вы бы описали задачу, а не представение о решении. Чего пытаетесь добиться? Для чего эти действия?

Comment: одно значение, через пробел либо через запятую 
нужно записывать в таблицу какая команда забила гол и на какой минуте

Answer (score 1):

Без применения макросов никак не получится удалить часть значения. Но если без удаления, то задача вполне реализуема с помощью условного форматирования (УФ) и форматов ячеек.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вариант1** (см. рис. столбцы *A:С*)

Данные разделить по столбцам - или при вводе, или формулами, ссылаясь на введеное значение. Если разбивать формулами:

```
=ЦЕЛОЕ(A2) или =--ЛЕВБ(A2)
=(A2-B2)*100 или =--ПРАВБ(ТЕКСТ(A2;"0,00");2)
```

В УФ использовать формулы, назначив форматам разные цвета:

```
=$B2=1 и =$B2=2
```

Т.к. столбец закреплен, это форматирование можно применить к двум столбцам C:B

**Вариант2** (см. рис. столбец *E*)

Данные не разделены. Формулы УФ:

```
=--ЛЕВБ(E2)=1 и =--ЛЕВБ(E2)=2
```

Для такого варианта желательно ячейкам присвоить формат числовой с двумя знаками после запятой (см. ячейку *E4*)

**Вариант3** (см. рис. столбец *G*)

В ячейку данные записываем "наоборот" - сначала время, потом команда. При этом не обрезаются нули у времени, кратного 10 (как в ячейке *E4*). А еще при такой записи можно отобразить только время: задаем формат ячейкам **00** (в меню *все_форматы*). Формат позволяет отображать только целую часть числа с двумя разрядами (4 мин будут отображены как 04)

Формулы УФ:

```
=--ПРАВБ(G2)=1 и =--ПРАВБ(G2)=2
```

**Примечание**

*ЦЕЛОЕ = INT*, *ТЕКСТ = TEXT*

*ПРАВБ, ЛЕВБ* недокументированы, в списке функций нет, аналоги - *ПРАВСИМВ, ЛЕВСИМВ* (*RIGHT, LEFT*)

Двойное отрицание преобразует текст в число.

Comment: добавлю, что ненужные столбцы в первом варианте всегда можно скрыть.